# SQLCMD :CONNECT with a specific port?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

In SSMS with TSQL is it possible to do a SQLCMD :CONNECT to a SQL Server with a specified port?

Something like this:

```
:CONNECT MySQLServer, 49603
```

I know there is the -S switch for SQLCMD in the command line, but for this I need to use TSQL in SSMS.

Comment: Just remove the space after the comma. `:CONNECT MySQLServer,49603`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can specify a port number as in your example (but with no space):

```
:CONNECT MySQLServer,49603
```

Comment: OMG, that works!  LOL.... and here I was I was trying it with a space.   Thank you!